# How do I install multiple packages from a command where some are obsolete?

Tags: package-management, software-installation

I'm trying to compile SLADE, a Doom editor, and I'm having an issue where the instructions require the installation of packages that are old, and because of this, I can't install the packages I need. I get an error like "unable to locate package" probably because it's obsolete. I can't figure out how to install all of the packages the instructions requires. I use the following command to install them:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libgtk2.0-dev libglew1.6-dev \
libfreeimage-dev libftgl-dev libfluidsynth-dev libsfml-dev \
libgstreamer0.10-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev libgconf2-dev \
freeglut3-dev cmake libmodplug-dev git libwebkit-dev libwxgtk3.0-dev \
libwxgtk-media3.0-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libwxgtk-webview3.0-dev libbz2-dev
```

All of the instructions for compiling this program are found [here](http://slade.mancubus.net/index.php?page=wiki&wikipage=Ubuntu-Step-by-Step-Compilation). Any help for making the process a lot less tedious and managable is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I had to add some mirrors to my list. This wasn't clear at first, but now I'm able to install the packages after doing this.